# Excel - selecting cells used in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to select all the cells in a formula? For example, cell G5 has the formula `(=+trial!G100+trial!G102+trial!G103)` and I want to copy values in the original cells and arrange them on another sheet. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the cells as you normally would.

Then rather than pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> you should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to initiate the [Paste Special](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Paste-Special-options-c31b7c9e-69ce-4b60-8c3a-dc5ea10d872c) command.

This will allow you to paste the values rather than the formulas.

Otherwise you can  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> as normal and then you will see a box pop up with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in it. If you press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then it will pop up with a list of paste options, one of those will be the option to paste values, it will be the little number icon you want.

[image]

If you right click before pasting then underneath the "Paste" option then will be a similar list of icons in 2007 or above.